# Python priorityQueue.get() returns int instead of object

Tags: python, search, queue

I am currently developing an AI system in python to solve the bloxorz game using the A* search algorithm.

Naturally, the algorithm stores the nodes in a priority queue,but when i try to get() an element from the queue, it returns an int instead of the object. As I am very new to python, I would appreciate it if someone can clarify.
My A* algorithm:

```
class Astar:
def __init__(self, start):
    self.path = []
    self.visitedQueue = []
    """hold visited in a queue to avoid duplicates"""
    self.priorityQueue = PriorityQueue()

    self.start = start

def Solve(self):
    """the a* algorithm"""
    StartNode = Node_Map(self.start, 0, self.start)
    count = 0
    self.priorityQueue.put(0, count, StartNode)
    while not self.path and self.priorityQueue.qsize():
        closestChild = self.priorityQueue.get()[2]
        closestChild.createChildren()
        self.visitedQueue.append(closestChild.matrix)
        for child in closestChild.children:
            if child.matrix not in self.visitedQueue:
                count += 1
                if child.getH == 0:
                    self.path = child.path
                    break
                self.priorityQueue.put(child.getH+count, count, child)
                """ put in priority queue according to f(n)=h(n)+g(n)"""
    if not self.path:
        print("goal not possible")
    return self.path
```

My Node class and Node_Map class:

```
class Node(object):
def __init__(self, matrix, parent, start=0):
    self.children = []
    self.matrix = {}
    self.parent = parent
    self.xPos = 0
    self.yPos = 0
    self.goalX = 0
    self.goalY = 0

    if parent:
        self.path = parent.path[:]
        self.start = parent.start
        self.path.append = [matrix]

    else:
        self.path = [matrix]
        self.start = start

def getDist(self):
    """ abstract function to get our estimated distance to the goal"""
    pass

def createChildren(self):
    """absract to create children from successor actions"""
    pass


class Node_Map(Node):
def __init__(self, matrix, parent, start=0):
    super(Node_Map, self).__init__(matrix, parent, start)
    self.h = self.getH()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
priorityQueue.put(child.getH+count, count, child)
```

The above line calls `put` with the arguments: `item=child.getH+count`, `block=count`, and `timeout=child`.  As a result, only `child.getH+count` is be considered as the 'item' that `get` will retrieve.  Try putting all three objects into a tuple:

```
priorityQueue.put((child.getH+count, count, child))
```

This way, `item` will be the tuple `(child.getH+count, count, child)`, and the other two arguments, `block`, and `timeout`, will stay as their default values (`True` and `None`, respectively).

Comment: Thank you. There was another put function call like that too, and after changing both to the format you mentioned, the error is no more.